# When I resubmit my app after being rejected, does the review start at the end of the line?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So my application was rejected because of a small problem that I fixed... Does my application start at the end of the line again, or does it go back to the same reviewer for review?

Does anyone know?

Comment: Sounds like you want to vote for [the App Store Stack Exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores).

Comment: I don't stand where I vote lol

Comment: I don't understand you, Arian, but that's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only i get a direct contact with reviewer of my app, it was the same person during reviewing process, but i don' t know if that's the rule. She asked me to correct a point, and did that, and after that she seen another point.

After the first reject, i put my phone number inside comments. So she can join me, and we had a direct talk about my app. May be you could give it a try.

Cdt